# Why is Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Https .NET 4.5.1 agnostic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, https, dnx, kestrel-http-server

I know that Kestrel is just a development webserver ATM and not really production ready since it is missing a couple of features, but on nuget there's a package (http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Https/1.0.0-rc1-final) that adds HTTPS support to the Kestrel server.

Now while Kestrel can be used against dotnet5.4 (without any dependencies), the Kestrel HTTPS package requires the full .NET 4.5.1 framework.

Is this due to actual platform requirements on Windows or just a mistake?

Comment: can be both ;) ... there are bugs for wrong references. But SSL support is in CoreFX build against OpenSSL ... which is used by everyone else out there ... so I think it will come. Maybe it is also a different speed topic. The ASP.Net team is concentrating right now a bit on kestrel, while corefx might not be able to deliver in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with RC2 of AspNetCore the HTTPS package only requires DotNetStandard1.3: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https/1.0.0-rc2-final